# Sed command inserts new line after execution - how to avoid?

Tags: unix, sed

I am trying to copy a line from one file to another and add characters to the same line afterwards.

```
cat $INDIR/files |
while read
do
sed -n 27p $INDIR/files >> $OUTDIR/files
for i in {1..6} ; do echo -n '0.000000e+00 '; done >> $OUTDIR/files
done
```

It should look like this:

```
copied text 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

But it looks like this:

```
copied text
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
```

How can I avoid the line break that is added to my output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this a try:

change your sed line into:

```
awk 'NR==27{printf "%s ", $0}' $INDIR/files >> $OUTDIR/files
```

as @devnull commented, you can also do:

```
sed .... |tr '\n' ' ' >>$OUTDIR/files
```

Comment: Another option would be to pipe `sed` output to `tr`, i.e. `tr '\n' ' '`

Comment: @devnull added in answer and thanx for adding the space. :)

Comment: @devnull - I was going to write that as an answer. Do you want to do it? It's quite different from saying "use awk" . The "real" trick would be to get `sed` to produce no newline in the first place... but I can't think of how to do that.

Comment: @Floris I'm not sure how to make `sed` produce no newline.  Of course, it's pretty different from using `awk`.